# How to handle subquery returning for IN clause having no rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a schema where employee details with location assigned are maintained in 'employee' table.

All roles assigned to location having count of max_limit, and assigned_count is in 'loc_role_limit' table

And all roles assigned to an employee is maintained in 'emp_role' table

Now when an employee is deactivated, I want to decrease assigned_count of that location and roles of that employee

```
UPDATE loc_role_limit lrl SET lrl.assigned_count = lrl.assigned_count + 1  
WHERE lrl.location = (select e.location from employee e where e.empCode = ?1)
    AND lrl.role IN  (select er.roleCode from empl_role er where er.empCode = ?1)
```

But, 1 problem is only when no role is assigned to an employee and wanted to deactivate

```
    AND lrl.role IN  (select er.roleCode from emp_role er where er.empCode = ?1)
```

then this IN clause will give empty list.

One way is I will do another query and if the size is more than 0, then I will call the UPDATE query.
But, again it will be 2 queries from application.

Is there any way I can handle this from the query side?

Comment: Why have you tagged MySQL and SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `EXISTS` query like

```
UPDATE loc_role_limit lrl SET lrl.assigned_count = lrl.assigned_count + 1  
WHERE lrl.location = (select e.location from employee e where e.empCode = ?1)
AND EXISTS  (select er.roleCode from empl_role er where er.empCode = ?1)
```